# Bind and monad stack

Tags: haskell

```
type IM = StateT (EnvFun, EnvEval) (ReaderT EnvEval (ErrorT String IO))


i :: Stmts -> IM
i Statements s (Statements e) = interpeteStmt s >>= \m  ...
```

And I have a problem with understanding. What is `m`. Yes, it is that, what `bind` for monad return. But which monad "is important". I cannot just understand because this monad stack makes me troub.e

Comment: What's the type of `interpeteStmt`?

Comment: please take your time and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - you have lot's of questions like this here and all would greatly benefit from you learning how to provide enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is a poorly chosen variable name here. The type of `>>=` is `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, so the variable `m` in the body of  `i` is bound to a value of type `a`. What type `a` is depends on what `interpeteStmt` returns.

Comment: interpeteStmt returns StateT (EnvFun, EnvEval) (ReaderT EnvEval (ErrorT String IO))